# How can I correct this entity association with Entity Framework Designer?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

I have the Product entity with a foreign key for the Brand entity (both keys are int identity and primary keys in their own table, but idBrand is a foreign key in Products. I am using SQL Server as my db

I would want to add products without having to add a brand first, is there any way to do this without having to disable the foreign key at product?

I thought some ways of dealing with this, but maybe there is one better...

1) Do not use Foreign keys, only one more table with both ids and idproduct unique.
2) Do not use Foreign keys at Product, only a Brand id int that could be empty.
3) Create a dumb Brand with code 1 called "No Brand" or something.

To better understand me, I want to design the relationship without having the obligation of providing a Brand to the Product entity when coding. Is there a way of design this from the Entity Framework Designer in VS ?

Thank you for stopping by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem, the association created in the designer was from 1 to many, I changed it to "0..1 to many", that solved the problem.

Thank you for reading.